# How to set QGIS options in standalone pyqgis application

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a standalone application which uses the QGS api to view and query map layers. One layer is a WMS-C layer which automatically caches tiles which is great. I want to also activate a setting which is present in QGIS but I can't work out how to implement it in my app, namely:

- Use render caching... (Settings -> Options -> Rendering)

I found the QSettings key for this in QGIS by browsing the output of:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
s = QSettings().allKeys()
for k in s:
    print k
```

The one I need to access/emulate/implement is:

```
Qgis/enable_render_caching
```

Where can I activate/implement these settings in my standalone app? Is this the setting that is read by [`QgsMapCanvas.setCachingEnabled(bool)`](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a1a7e584be7199e1e8cc7590dbf129311)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I activate/implement these settings in my standalone app? Is this the setting that is read by `QgsMapCanvas.setCachingEnabled(bool)`?

Yes, to the latter. That is what is called when the [Options dialog is confirmed and closed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgisapp.cpp#L7313).

Oddly, the caching setting is only read in on `QgisApp::QgisApp` initialization [when `QgisApp::createOverview()` is called](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgisapp.cpp#L2226). In any event, the default is ON until otherwise set by the user.

Using `QgsMapCanvas.setCachingEnabled(bool)` should change caching the setting on-demand for you in your PyQGIS app.

To set the `qgis/enable_render_caching` (note the key may be case-sensitive on some platforms, i.e. it is 'qgis', not 'Qgis'), see [how it is done in QgsOptions](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsoptions.cpp#L1072).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think to find it on GitHub - I should have checked, I would have found the answer!